# Linking to the Google Maps reviews of a place?

Tags: google-maps

I can display info of a place on google map using the url

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=eiffel+tower+paris
```

However, I'd like to link to the reviews of the place which you get when you click on the number of reviews.

Is there a simple url like the above which can search for a place on google map and switch to the reviews immediately? Like some additional parameter for the above url to switch to the reviews panel.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Google Maps

If you search and navigate to the place you want on https://maps.google.com. Then scroll the left-hand side panel down until you see the **Review Summary**. By clicking on the total number of reviews, the address bar in your browser will then be updated to a link that you can use to send someone to this panel.

For instance, here is a link I was able to generate for a tourist destination:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Glen+Canyon+Dam/@36.9369499,-111.4859917,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0x8739d46fcc1d6c6b:0x409adb24f99ef4f5!2sLake+Powell,+AZ+86040!3b1!8m2!3d36.9388464!4d-111.4847167!3m6!1s0x87346b2e4e555555:0xa7f0bd48dc75ca45!8m2!3d36.937199!4d-111.4836681!9m1!1b1

Unfortunately, it is not a simple link. But it is easily produced.

## Using Google's Review API

Google has restricted review data in such a way that it is only accessible through their API.

Some time ago, you were to be able to embed your google reviews in an `iframe` using a link that was provided to you by google. Nowadays, one of the ways to leverage this API is to use a widget that comes with your CMS (if you are using one), you can also setup Google's My Business API, and pull reviews that way. Do note that it involves registering your app with google as well.

> [Reviews] used to be relatively easy to embed a few years ago, but Google has since phased this solution out.<sup>[[1]](https://blog.reviews.io/how-to-add-google-reviews-to-your-website)</sup>

## Links

1: https://blog.reviews.io/how-to-add-google-reviews-to-your-website

2: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

Comment: I don't want to get the reviews on my site, I don't want to embed them. I want to link to the reviews panel of any place on google maps, so the reviews tab is shown automatically on maps.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer!

Comment: I know how to get the reviews link of one particular place.  I'd like a generic link where I can put any place name in it to show the reviews immediately. Like this hypotetical url: "maps.google.com/maps?q=eiffel+tower+paris&action=showreviews"

Comment: If such an action exists, it might not be documented. I'm checking under **Launch Google Maps and perform a specific action** found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#forming-the-url